# Create query in sparql using jena without hard coding the query?

Tags: sparql, jena

Can any one tell me how to create a sparql query for dbpedia using jena program without hard coding the query.. I dont want to just store the query in string and to execute it... I have no idead how to make it as i am new to sparql... Could any one plz help me..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add more detail on what you want to do i.e. is there a general template to your queries or particular types of queries you want to make?

Jena does have some support for substituting variables into prepared queries so you can hard code a template and then substitute values as desired based on your inputs.  But whether this is applicable depends on what queries you want to make.

As a very simple solution you can just build your querystring by string concatenation based on your inputs and then use Jena to send that to DBpedia.

**Edit**

See Ian's answer to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694091/create-query-in-sparql-using-jena-without-hard-coding-the-query) which shows how to do substitution of values into prepared queries using Jena